WordPress wp_editor replaces " double quotes with “ in html tags (e.g. links, images or tables)
I'm facing an issue with the wp_editor (TinyMCE) in WordPress 6.5.3 (latest) where the quotes in my content are being replaced incorrectly. I'm using a custom shortcode (handled by WPCode) to display an editable content area on a post, but when the content is loaded into the editor, the double quotes (") are being replaced with “ entities, causing display issues.
Code snippet:
<?php
wp_editor($editable_content, 'post_content', [
    'textarea_name' => 'post_content',
    'textarea_rows' => 20,
]);
//error_log($editable_content);
?>

Example:
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/L%C3%B6we_1.jpg" alt="" />
is displayed (not stored) as:
<img src=“https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/L%C3%B6we_1.jpg“ alt=““ />
and after using the visual editor:
<img src="“https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/L%C3%B6we_1.jpg“" alt="““" />
I have already tried the following approaches to resolve the issue, but none of them worked:

Using the remove_filter function to remove wptexturize or wp_filter_post_kses

Modifying the TinyMCE settings


The issue persists, and the quotes are still being replaced incorrectly in the editor. It's possible that I'm not using the remove_filter function correctly before calling wp_editor.
I've also ensured that the $editable_content variable contains the correct content before passing it to wp_editor.
I have been facing the problem for more than a day now, I would appreciate your help.
If you need any additional information, please let me know.

I had the same issue with wp_editor(). The problem is indeed with wptexturize, and remove_filter didn't work either. To solve the issue, we can completely disable it as follows:
add_filter('run_wptexturize', '__return_false');

However, if we want to keep wptexturize, we can disable it only for content inside textarea:
function my_no_texturize_tags($tags) {
    $tags[] = 'textarea';
    return $tags;
}
add_filter('no_texturize_tags', 'my_no_texturize_tags');

It will no longer interfere with the content sent to wp_editor().

For the record, while wptexturize can't be disabled directly in the wp_editor() settings, we can disable wpautop (if needed) like this:
wp_editor($editable_content, 'post_content', [
    'textarea_name' => 'post_content',
    'textarea_rows' => 20,
    'wpautop' => false,
]);

